# How to convert values to string?

Tags: java, string, collections

I have a problem with converting values to string. I have a method that return a list collection:

```
public String getDispenserActivityCsvReportAllRows() throws IOException {
    csvDataReader = new CSVDataReader();
    waitForPageTitle();
    CSVDataReader.deleteFilesFromDefaultDownloadDir();
    downloadCsvFileButton.click();
    String downloadPath = "src/main/documents/";
    String filename = getDispenserReportCsvFileName();
    File file = new File(downloadPath + filename);
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file));
    List<String[]> rows = reader.readAll();
        for (String[] row: rows) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
        }
        reader.close();

    return rows.toString();
}
```

But it returns values like: Ljava.lang.String;@b27b210, [Ljava.lang.String;@69aa7d76, [Ljava.lang.String;@33f17289, [Ljava.lang.String;@f1266c6]. How to convert it into normal values like "Something".